# Style tag with all CSS in HTML

Tags: css, audit, lighthouse

So I'm trying to improve our audit results massively. Currently a lot is done wrong which needs improvement. However, one of the tests is the following:

```
Eliminate render-blocking resources
```

And Lighthouse gives the following suggestion:

```
Resources are blocking the first paint of your page. Consider delivering critical JS/CSS inline and deferring all non-critical JS/styles. Learn more.
```

So I assume with that they mean the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            /* CSS RULES HERE */
        </style>
    </head>
</html>
```

But I always learnt it like you shouldn't mix HTML/CSS. Is there another way around this "problem" or is the only way to solve it by using something like the example above?

Comment: "But I always learnt it like you shouldn't mix HTML/CSS.":
1) This is not a mixing of html/css
2) There is no rule of "not mixing html/css"

Comment: You should place your critical css (=some basic styles so your page will look similar even without others css files) in the header and then defer loading of the css files.

Comment: So the example which I put in my question is the right way to do it?

Comment: The "right way" is a matter of opinion. The example is the way that produces the best performing web pages. You have to trade that for poorer separation of concerns. Better separation would be to put the CSS in its own file, but that will mean the page will take longer to render, at least on the user's first visit.

Comment: @Alohci Ah I understand, makes sense now.